# Select2, Symfony: Autocomplete with remote data not working

Tags: javascript, symfony, jquery-select2

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete search when searching for a city on my website (carpooling).
I made a controller searchCity which return a json with the cities:

```
 /**
 * @Route ("/city/{term}")
 */
public function searchCity($term)
{
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Ville')
        ->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('v.id, v.nomReel AS text')
        ->where('v.nomSimple LIKE :term')
        ->setParameter('term', $term.'%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $query = array('results' => $query);
    return new JsonResponse($query);
}
```

For exemple if I go to /city/Paris I'll get :

```
    {"results":[
        {"id":30438,"text":"Paris"},
        {"id":29427,"text":"Paris-l\u0027H\u00f4pital"}, //I know single quotes
        {"id":33294,"text":"Parisot"},                   //don't work
        {"id":33531,"text":"Parisot"}]}
```

select :

```
<div class="container">
    <select id="citySelect" class="select2 select2-dropdown select2-search" name="term">
    </select>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#citySelect").select2({
                placeholder: "Select city",
                ajax: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: function (params) {
                        return '/city/' + params.term;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                                return { id: obj.ime, text: obj.ime };
                            })
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

When I search a city nothing shows up (searching ... and nothing)
with the console log I can see that data is there and well formated but the cities are not showing on the dropdown menu. 
I think that my problem is with my javascript code and my comprehension of select2.

Regards

UPDATE :

js :

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".select2").select2({
                placeholder: "Select city",
                ajax: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: function (params) {
                        return '/city/' + params.term;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: data.results //return data directly
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess when transforming data you wanted

```
return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text };
```

instead of

```
return { id: obj.ime, text: obj.ime };
```

Also looking at the json you posted you could probably (not tested) just do

```
processResults: function (data) {
    return {
        results: data.results;
    };
}
```